# App that monitors other Apps - is this even possible?

Tags: android, ios

Not sure if what I want to do is possible - and would appreciate any advice.

I want my APP (on iPhone, Android and maybe Windows) to be loaded and then to effectively monitor the device screen, until a particular 32x32 (or whatever) set of pixels appears. Think maybe Facebook being loaded up and a picture being present that contains this particular pre defined pattern - my APP to then 'does something'....
....If it could also monitor whether the user click on this pattern then better still.

Is this possible - and if so how would you go about it?

Phil

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop app that gives user opportunity to monitor apps that are running on another devices and handle touches inside these apps, it may be done with help of server.

In general (until more details will be given) each app must do screenshots and handle touches and immediately send them to server. And server must send this info to all devices that subscribed to updates from particular set of devices. On other hand, client app must get updates from the server constantly.

But you should be aware that Apple may reject such application (for activity similar to spying activity), so I suggest you read in details about Apple opinion for this case.

Comment: Thanks, but it was monitoring inside the same device I was thinking of.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to gain such functionality on standart iOS devices without jailbreak.
If device already jailbroken there may be some ways to do this, but I personally have no experience in such cases.